# How can I check the inputted text to see if it matches the answer or not?

Tags: java, android, input

I have recently made another project which has some questions and some EditTexts in Android Studio with Java language. It's a small project, and I want to check the texts the players entered to see if they're correct or not. If yes then I'll make a message that says "Correct", and if not then the "Wrong" message will appear. I have tried this:

```
 String str = monkey.getText().toString();
 if(str.matches("LION")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

But it didn't work. I searched this question on the Internet and got no answer. Does anybody knows how to answer this question? If yes, then thanks a lot!

Comment: You might be interested in browsing the [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html). Are you looking for `.equals (Object otherString)` or `,equalsIgnoreCase (String otherString)`?

Comment: I wanted to see if  the inputted text and the answer matches, but the str.matches("LION") seems to be for regex

Comment: So, try `if (str.equals ("LION"))` or `if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Lion"))`  Does that work for you?  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: I've already tried if (str.equals ("LION")), but well, it didn't work too.

Comment: You need to include more details - *where* is the code you posted located in your Activity or Fragment? Most likely, it is in the wrong place so the check either doesn't run or runs before the user can actually enter any text.

Comment: I agree -- you need to add more details to your question. (1) How do you define "if they're correct"? (2) Your code shows what should happen if the response is correct. But, it doesn't show what should happen if not correct. This raises the question, suggested in the previous comment, "How do you know the `if` is actually reached?"  (3) Please edit the question to show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: If you have not done so, use a debugger. It might be `str` doesn't contain what you think it does. It could, for example, have whitespace at the end. In any case, knowing how to debug is necessary if you want to develop software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str matches is for regex matching

If you need match the exact answer you can use something like
str.matches("^LION$")

If you need the answer to just include the answer you want you can use something like

str.matches(".*LION.*")

Comment: I tried to do so, but the code still have the word "regex" before the text. Why?